# kotlin: "unresolved reference" in secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin, constructor

i am very new to kotlin, and maybe this might be a silly question but why using a variable defined in a secondary parameter gives an error of "unresolved reference" when i try to print it while the same does not happen in case of primary constructor

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){    
    var stud= Student("Yash", 10)    
}

class Student(name: String) {
    init {
        println("name is $name")
    }

    constructor(n: String, Id: Int): this(n) {
       println("name is $n")
       println("id is $id")
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it'll work if you make it `val name: String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter id is small letter,but you are try to print capital letter Id, change like this its working now

> constructor(n: String, id: Int)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
var stud= Student("Yash", 10)
}

class Student(name: String) {
init {
    println("name is $name")
}

constructor(n: String, id: Int): this(n) {
    println("name is $n")
    println("id is $id")
}
}
```